# How is it possible that a user is able to create duplicate account?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am truly puzzled by this.

We were giving a spec to build an app that requires users to create their own accounts before using the app.

The spec says that user's email should be validated against the email s/he has on our database.

If that email already exists, inform the user and ask him/her to choose another.

Below is the code that does all that.

**//Markup:**

```
<tr>
   <td height="27" width="129"><font face="Tahoma" size="2">
   <label for="txtEmail">Your Email address:</label></font></td>
   <td height="27" width="244">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="Treb10Blue" Runat="server"  style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; color: #000080;"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" Runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression=".*@.*\..*" ErrorMessage="Email not in correct format" Display="Dynamic" Runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**//Then codebehind**

```
Function Fixquotes(ByVal thesqlenemy As String) As String
    Fixquotes = Replace(thesqlenemy, "'", "''")
End Function

Sub btnRegister_Onclick(ByVal Src As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    If Page.IsValid Then
        Dim objConn As IDbConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim chkUsername As IDbCommand
        Dim addUser As IDbCommand
        Dim strSQL1 As String
        Dim strSQL2 As String
        Dim strUserCount As Integer

    'first, check if user already exists
        Try
            strSQL1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tblLogin] WHERE [Email]='" & Fixquotes(txtEmail.Text) & "'"
            strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO [tblLogin] ([Fullname], [Email], [Username], [Password],[Rights],[ModifiedDate],Precinct,PositionId,ProcessedFlag)"
            strSQL2 = strSQL2 & " VALUES "
            strSQL2 = strSQL2 & "('" & Fixquotes(txtFullname.Text) & "', '" & Fixquotes(txtEmail.Text) & "', '" & Fixquotes(txtUsername.Text) & "', '" & Fixquotes(txtPassword.Text) & "',2,getdate(), '" & precinctList.SelectedValue & "'," & PosisitionList.SelectedValue & ",'No')"
            'Response.Write(strSQL2)
            'Response.End()
            objConn.Open()
            chkUsername = New SqlCommand(strSQL1, objConn)
            strUserCount = chkUsername.ExecuteScalar()
            If strUserCount = 0 Then
                addUser = New SqlCommand(strSQL2, objConn)
                addUser.ExecuteNonQuery()
                objConn.Close()
                'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was sent
                lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                lblMsg.Text = "Your account has been successfully created.<br><br>Please click the Close button below to close this window and log in with your newly created username and password."


                'Clear the form
                txtFullname.Text = ""
                txtEmail.Text = ""

            Else
                lblMsg.Text = "That email address already exists. Please choose another..."
                lblMsg.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        Catch

            objConn.Close()

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

So far, out of a total of 1,035 users who have signed up, nine (9) of them have been able to create duplicate accounts using SAME email address.

One of those users did it 5 times!

How is this possible and how do I prevent further occurences?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: FYI, `Fixquotes` is not a way to sanitize input to make your SQL safe. Use parameterized queries, and also should look into `Using` statements, as it doesn't look like you are closing your connection properly (like in the Else statement), which may contribute to your problem.

Comment: See if you are able to replicate the issue by refreshing the page just after you complete the registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but 5 times seems hard to do. More than likely, the users double-clicked, which caused the code to run twice. Now, because there is a period of time between your query to see if it exists and the time you create it, it is possible to create multiples.

To fix this, there are several ways.

You can look at implementing transactions in your code [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

You can implement transactions in your SQL [SQL Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx)

Or, my favorite, write your SQL in a way that is tranactional
Put both SQL Statements into 1 string that starts with "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [tblLogin] WHERE [Email]='" & Fixquotes(txtEmail.Text) & "' " & YourInsertSqlHere

Then, when you run this SQL using ExecuteNonQuery(), keep the result which if 0, means it did NOT insert because it already existed.

But first, fix the double-click issue by disabling the button when they click before you do anything else!

Comment: Ah yes, you should also do what @Karl Anderson said

Answer (score 2):

You probably have requests happening in very quick succession, and in the time between the queries executing, the value is no longer unique. Encapsulating everything in a transaction would prevent this, and as far as practices go you should look into putting that in a stored procedure.

Comment: All, thank you very much for your majestic responses.

Everything said so far is true.

Karl's solution is superb but I can't implement the change now because I was told not to delete any duplicate for fear of deleting records associated with them.

James is absolutely right as well because these users are rushing against time to get signed up before a 10/5/2013. That, I think created the reason for concurrent signups.

For now, I have implemented the quickest solution which is to disable the submit button after clicking it.

I will handle rest of your suggestions later.

Many thanks to ALL!

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop duplicate entries is to stop duplicate data from even getting into the database by putting a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `[Email]` column in your database table.

Then, at least, an exception would be thrown when the duplicate `INSERT` attempt happened.